# EmberJS in combination with Ember-Runner

Tags: node.js, build, ember.js

Good day,

I just started with EmberJS in combination with [Ember-Runner](https://github.com/envone/ember-runner). I found an working example on [Github](https://github.com/envone/ember-runner-sample).

Ember-runner automaticly adds all your template files and JS (at least that is what I thought) together and generarates a singe HTML / JS / templates / CSS file from your own files every time you save. (And optionally minify's and such). A build tool, just like it says in the description.

This is what it does for the CSS and templates part, however for the JS part it only seems to include only one file in my JS folder which is called 'main.js'. Is it possible to scan that dir for other files so it includes those as well? (So I can have separate controller / model files and such).

I hope my question is clear.

Kind regards,

Matthijn Dijkstra